# How to open a submenu link in a new window with jquery

Tags: jquery, magento

I'm trying to open a link within a submenu with jquery. The code below is working to open a top-level menu item but I'm unsure of the proper way to target the submenu items.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#navigation > li.nav-5 > a').attr('target', '_blank');
  });
</script>
```

The website I'm attempting to set this up on is http://www.legacysportscards.com

Comment: The only difference is the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target the href directly instead of traversing the menu tree.:

```
$('a[href*="http://google.com"]').attr('target', '_blank');
```

Comment: This works perfectly and in the end is a better option for our site. Thanks!